# How to make Mac Terminal restore working directories when restarting

Tags: terminal

I use the Mac Terminal with a hand full of tabs each assigned to a different working directory. I have configured it to open new windows with the same working directory. Nevertheless, when I am quitting Terminal, and restart it it rebuilds all the tabs, their names, even shows me the last output in the window but stays in the user home directory and does not restore the latest working directory of each tab.

What am I doing wrong? Can this be caused by some setting in the `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: I think you can find what you are looking for in this thread. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-can-i-open-multiple-customized-terminal-shells

Comment: So am I wrong in assuming this should be supported out of the box?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(For reference, we’re talking about the Resume feature of Mac OS X Lion 10.7 and later.)

Terminal automatically restores the working directory if you’re using the default shell, bash. If you’re using some other shell, you’ll need to adapt the code in `/etc/bashrc` to send an escape sequence to communicate the working directory to Terminal so it can restore the directory later for Resume. If you’re using zsh, see my answer to [Resume Zsh-Terminal (OS X Lion)](https://superuser.com/a/328148/81175), in which I include the appropriate code for zsh.

If you have a custom `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` you may need to ensure that you’re not undoing the default behavior by modifying `/etc/bashrc`’s customizations. In particular, it sets the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable to send the escape sequence at each prompt. If you customize that variable, you’ll need to prefix or append your code to the current value, e.g.:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="<your code here>;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Also, generally, `~/.bash_profile` should execute `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't seem to be able to get that working. I have removed my `.bashrc` (although I couldn't spot any prompt command customization. Now I do the following:

1. Open a new Terminal window (opens in my user's home directory)
2. cd Documents
3. Quit Terminal
4. Open Terminal
5. Window reopens displaying the directory change output but still located in the user's home directory.

Comment: @OliverGierke Terminal creates login shells, so also check for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`.

Comment: I don't have the latter two, the former now executes `~/.bashrc` as per your suggestion in your answer.

Comment: I got it figured out, Chris. My `/etc/bashrc` seems to have been tweaked by an install script or whatever. There was a `/etc/bashrc.orig` that contained some additional config (which I assume to be the original setup) https://gist.github.com/3273170. Re-adding that to the `/etc/bashrc` made things working as expected again. Thanks a lot for help and patience!

Comment: I don't change the $PROMPT_COMMAND in my .bashrc and I only have the system default /etc/bashrc. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Apple has documented this behavior in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bash-It, you may run into the problem of `$PROMPT_COMMAND` being overwritten by it.

As mentioned it is used by OS X to restore cwd in new tabs. Bash it should append values, not override them.

But a workaround for now would be to add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
source $BASH_IT/bash_it.sh
export PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND;update_terminal_cwd;"
```

For more info checkout the issue tracker for updates:
https://github.com/revans/bash-it/issues/240

And the Apple reference for it
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/sh.1.html

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a [blog post](http://russellfinn.com/2013/10/25/current-working-directory-restoration-in-mavericks-terminal-with-tcsh/) on how to do this for csh/tcsh before I discovered this answer; if anyone else comes here looking for a solution for those shells, here it is:

```
if ("$?TERM_PROGRAM") then
  if ("$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal") then
    alias precmd 'printf "\033]7;%s\a" "file://$host$cwd:ags/ /%20/"'
  endif
endif
```

Add that to your `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc` as appropriate. (The outer if statement is necessary to avoid an error when remotely logging in, as with ssh. It has to be a separate statement because of the variable expansion rules in tcsh.)

Like Apple's builtin bash support, this solution uses no external programs other than `printf`, at the cost of only escaping spaces. If you need to escape other special characters, you'll have to work a little harder to find a more comprehensive solution.